# Django Check and set permissions for a user group

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a **usergroup** called **baseusers** with a set of permissions I have added via admin. If **baseusers** doesn't exist I want to create it and set the same permissions it has now. I can create the group but how do I find out the permissions from shell and then add them in my code? For example two of the permissions are named **can_fm_list** and **can_fm_add**. Application is called **fileman**. But do I need to use id:s instead? Here is the code I would like the permissions to be set.

`userprofile/views.py`

```
from fileman.models import Setting (Has the permissions)
from fileman.models import Newuserpath
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def register(request):

...

            if Group.objects.count() > 0:
            newuser.groups.add(1)
            else:
            newgroup = Group(name='baseusers')
            newgroup.save()
            newuser.groups.add(1)
```

`fileman/models.py`

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    owner = AutoForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='fileman_Setting')
    root = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    home = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    buffer = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_fm_list", _("Can look files list")),
            ("can_fm_add", _("Can upload files")),
            ("can_fm_rename", _("Can rename files")),
            ("can_fm_del", _("Can move files to basket")),
            ("can_fm_destruct", _("Can delete files")),
        )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.owner)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Setting, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.root:
            self.root = None
            self.home = None
    def writeBuffer(self, data):
        self.buffer = data
        self.save()
```

Comment: I tried mygroup = Group.objects.get(name='baseusers') and then mygroup.permissions.add(can_fm_list) but I get a 'can_fm_list' is not defined. I found out the id:s by doing a mygroup.permissions.values_list('id',flat=True). I can add them by id but I don't really like adding the permissions by id:s since they will be wrong if they change for some reason but can't figure out the other way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post: [Django: Using The Permission System](http://web.archive.org/web/20130205133031/http://parand.com/say/index.php/2010/02/19/django-using-the-permission-system/)

Adapted to your example:

```
can_fm_list = Permission.objects.get(name='can_fm_list')
newgroup.permissions.add(can_fm_list)
```

Comment: I tried mygroup = Group.objects.get(name='baseusers') and then mygroup.permissions.add(can_fm_list) but I get a 'can_fm_list' is not defined. I found out the id:s by doing a mygroup.permissions.values_list('id',flat=True). I can add them by id but I don't really like adding the permissions by id:s since they will be wrong if they change for some reason but can't figure out the other way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to do the can_fm_list = Permission... It works! Thanks!

Comment: Really appreciated the use of an archive.org URL to avoid URL rot!

Comment: What if I want to add multiple permissions? I will need to call add multiple times or is there an easy way?

Comment: To add multiple permissions, do the following: `newgroup.permissions = [permission1, permission2]` where `permission1` and `permission2` are objects of the Permission model.

Answer (score 8):

For others who are looking for adding multiple permissions at once,

```
permissions_list = Permission.objects.all()
new_group.permissions.set(permissions_list)
```

Comment: How would one do when using the `.add()` method? I'm assuming that using `.set()` replaces any previously set permissions

Comment: @kunambi - I know you probably already know, but for anybody else: `new_group.permissions.add(*permissions_list)`

Comment: @ZainPatel How do I add only permission for this current model, not all permissions as same as superuser?

Comment: You would probably need to use Django permission groups set as a foreign key to the model you want to use

Answer (score 0):

list of permissions add to a new group :-

```
group_name = request.POST.get('group_name')
permissions_list = request.POST.getlist('permission')
permissions_list_id = []
new_group = Group.objects.create(name=group_name)

for perm in permissions_list:
    p = Permission.objects.get(name=perm)
    permissions_list_id.append(p.id)

new_group.permissions.set(permissions_list_id)
```